# Communiation with multiple clients via Sockets

Tags: java, .net, sockets

I have a Server Socket and 3-4 android devices as clients. I'm using TCP/IP for communications. Which is the best method. Should I use multiple ports for each client? Or should I use same port. If using same function then how should I identify the communication addressed to different devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one port.  The client can send you its id.  If it can't you can look at the clients IP address to workout which one it is.

There are thousands of  TCP client/server code examples on the web, but I would start with the sample code which comes with the JDK,

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need several ports.

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
while (true)
{
    Socket socket = server.accept();
    // do something with this socket - aka 1 client

    new SomeClientClass(socket);
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        in.read(byte[]);
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream;
        // out will only write response to its own client.

    // when this new SomeClientClassis created, method returns to this point 
    // in while loop and waits for the next client

}
```

Comment: well, I have such structure for a service listening to 32 clients connecting "simultaneously". There was not a single problem with this part. "Simulateneously" in our eyes is not the same as in CPU's